# onClick not routing to the correct page the second time

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a signup functionality with additional checks for duplicate usernames on the client side (since Firestore doesn't allow you to set up rules for this). What happens is that if the user manages to sign up without any problems, it goes onto the next (onboarding) page `('/onboarding')` with no problems. However, if I encounter an error (if there is an error, I will change the state of `error` to show a notification) and then correct that error and click on the submit button again, it will send me to the home page `('/')` (and not the onboarding page, because the onboarding page is a Private route). Basically, if a user is successfully able to register, they should be directed to the onboarding page.

On the second time, I can see the user being created in my firestore collection, but just the `history.push()` statement does not work, so I'm not sure why that is happening. Below is my code

```
const signupFunc = async () => {
        await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value, usernameRef.current.value).then(cred => {
                createUser(cred.user.uid, usernameRef.current.value, emailRef.current.value)
                setError('')
                history.push('/onboarding')
            }).catch(() => setError('This email is already in use. Please try a different email'))
    }
```

This function is called within the checkAvailability function, which is used to first run the submitted values by the firestore collection to see if the username already exists

```
const checkAvailability = async () => {
    await checkUsernameAvailability(usernameRef.current.value).then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.docs.length === 0) {

        signupFunc()

        } else {

            throw Error()

        }
    }).catch(() => setError('Please pick another username'))
}

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    setError('')

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfRef.current.value) {
        setError('Password does not match')
    }

    else if (usernameRef.current.value.length < 2) {
        setError('Username should at least have two characters')
    }

    else {
        checkAvailability() 
    }
        
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you are using firestore for auth, because firebase provides auth services which handles all of this heavy lifting

Comment: @GayatriDipali I am using firestore to save additional information that firebase does not automatically store using auth - username, photo, etc.

Comment: Yeah I know, what you can do is let the users sign up using email, password. Now create a profile page and then update the particular properties of the user

Comment: Check this docs page for managing additional user data : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0

Comment: @GayatriDipali I have already checked this - my main concern is that I also would like to ensure that usernames are unique - which I cannot do through the displayName property as far as I know. That's why I'm creating a separate collection so that I can query the collection to see that the username does not exist

Comment: Wait what is route for register, is it `/register`

Comment: @GayatriDipali that is /signup - (which the code is a part of). Here, I want to route the user to /onboarding on successful signup, or show an error message. If the user resubmits the form with correct info, I want to route them to /onboarding, but currently they're being routed to / (default redirect for accessing private page without logging in; only happens on second sign up attempt). Seems like this issue only exists if username is duplicate or username/password length check errors (see checkAvailability and handleSubmit). For the duplicate email error (signupFunc) it works perfectly